# wordpress display all used categories per custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to display all used categories per custom post type, for example on the projects page, I show all projects, and at the top I want to add loop all used categories for projects. When I use wp_list_categories() it wil show ALL categories, even the onces that are not related to the cpt projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent'  => 0,
    'exclude' => 1
) );
```

Loop through

```
<?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { ?>

<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>
<?php echo $cat->name; ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

And then

```
query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=3&cat=-1&paged='. get_query_var('paged'));
```

Comment: This will show ALL categories, even the onces that are not used by the CPT 'projects'

Answer (score 0):

You should save all the categories when you loop through your posts, in an array or other data structure you find useful.

Using an associative array would be a simple solution. With category as key and category archive URL as value, you would have all the components needed to create a link to each category.

`['category 1' => 'http://yoururl.com/category1',...]`

**Example**

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    ...
    // using $category, get the title and URL for it
}
```

From here you can get all the properties you need for each category.

Comment: I need this outside the loop

Comment: You'll need to loop the `$posts` twice, then. In the first one, get the categories, in the next, render the posts.